# Why does GetLastError() return 0 or 2 depending on how it is called?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, exception, mingw

I am using mingw g++ 4.6.1 with -O0, WinXP SP2.

[Minimal working example is here.](http://szte-wsn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/szte-wsn/private/ali/min_ex/main.cpp?revision=2917&view=markup)

g++ is configured with --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2.

`GetLastError()` returns 0 or 2 depeding on how the exception is thrown:

```
throw runtime_error(error_message());
```

bogus "error code: 0" is printed, and

```
const string msg = error_message();

throw runtime_error(msg);
```

prints "error code: 2" as expected.

First, I thought `GetLastError()` is invoked twice but debugging shows it is invoked exactly once, as expected.

What is going on?

Comment: What happens if you modify your code to call `error_message(GetLastError())`?

Comment: You realize, of course, that "GetLastError()", C++ try/catch exceptions, and Win32 "Structured Exception Handling" (SEH) are all three different (related, but different) things, don't you?  You typically use one or another, but you *shouldn't* generally use them *together*, in conjunction with each other.

Comment: @GregHewgill I want to hide GetLastError(), and I would like to use error_message() instead.

Comment: @paulsm4 Please give more details. Also, please suggest a solution using C++ try/catch exceptions.

Comment: Visual Studio produces the correct output in both cases, so the mingw compiler must be generating code in the first case that alters the last error code.  Take a look at the generated assembly and I think you'll find some sort of system call

Comment: @ChetSimpson: I agree that something is calling a Win32 function, but that function doesn't have to fail to alter the error code.  Many Win32 functions alter the error code even on success.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yep, that is what Greg Hewgill says. Anyhow, thanks for testing it with Visual Studio.

Comment: I was wondering where this question went :)  I had the same MSVC result as @CareyGregory.  Works as intended and displays lasterror 2.

Comment: @JoeFish Yeah, I should have started the previous question with a minimal working example. That would have saved us a lot of time. Anyhow, thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible that the code that sets up a `throw` calls a Win32 API function inside itself somewhere, that resets the Last-Error value to 0. This may be happening *before* your call to `error_message()`.

Calling `GetLastError()` does *not* automatically reset the Last-Error value to 0, so it is safe to call twice.

Whether your compiler/runtime generates code that calls a Win32 API function will be up to your specific runtime. In order to be safe and not depend on this, use the two-statement version:

```
const string msg = error_message();
throw runtime_error(msg);
```

Better yet, for future readers of your code it would be useful to call `GetLastError()` outside `error_message()`:

```
const string msg = error_message(GetLastError());
throw runtime_error(msg);
```

This way, readers will see the `GetLastError()` call immediately after the corresponding Win32 API call, where it belongs.

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the assembly code generated, it become clear what's happening.  The following C++ code:

```
hDevice = CreateFileA(path, // drive to open
    // etc...
    );

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // cannot open the drive  
{                                                              
    throw runtime_error(error_message());
}
```

Generates a stretch of assembly code (at least using default optimization):

```
    call    _CreateFileA@28  #
LEHE4:
    sub esp, 28  #,
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], eax  # hDevice, D.51673
    cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-12], -1   # hDevice,
    jne L5   #,
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 8   #,

    call    ___cxa_allocate_exception    # // <--- this call is made between the 
                                             # //    CreateFile() call and the 
                                             # //    error_message() call

    mov ebx, eax     # D.50764,
    lea eax, [ebp-16]    # tmp66,
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax     #, tmp66
LEHB5:
    call    __Z13error_messagev  #
```

You see a call made to `___cxa_allocate_exception` to allocate some memory block for the exception being thrown.  That function call is changing the `GetLastError()` state.

When the C++ code looks like:

```
hDevice = CreateFileA(path, // drive to open
    // etc...
    );

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // cannot open the drive  
{                                                              
    const string msg = error_message();

    throw runtime_error(msg);
}
```

Then you get the following generated assembly:

```
    call    _CreateFileA@28  #
    sub esp, 28  #,
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], eax  # hDevice, D.51674
    cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-12], -1   # hDevice,
    jne L5   #,
    lea eax, [ebp-16]    # tmp66,
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], eax     #, tmp66
    call    __Z13error_messagev  #
LEHE4:
    sub esp, 4   #,
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], 8   #,

    call    ___cxa_allocate_exception  # // <--- now this happens *after*
                                         //     error_message() has been called
```

which does not call an external function between the failed `CreateFile()` call and the call to `error_message()`.

This kind of problem is one of the main problems with error handling using some global state like `GetLastError()` or `errno`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your efforts. Can suggest a clean solution to resolve this issue? Or is Greg Hewgill's answer the best we can do?

Comment: Greg Hewgill's answer is the correct way to approach this (this answer was really just trying to make Greg's point concrete). Since you don't really have control over what a compiler does to implement `throw` (or any other statement for that matter), you can't have a `throw` statement thrown into the mix of getting the `GetLastError()` status. You have to `GetLastError()` strictly before the `throw`.